# Selecting Native Tabs while Espresso testing

Tags: tabs, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-espresso

I have a viewpager which utilizes the native actionbar Tabs as the indicator. I would like to navigate to different tabs, but Tab component is not a view therefore, onView, or withText does not work properly with perform clicks.

Is there a specific way I can do to navigate through the Tab navigation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use swiping to navigate between your tabs:

```
onView(withId(R.id.viewpager)).perform(swipeLeft());
onView(withId(R.id.viewpager)).perform(swipeRight());
```

Comment: How do you then check if the title of a selected tab matches a String?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming there is text on the tab, you can do:

```
onView(withText("Tab Text")).perform(click())
```

onView, withText and click are static imports.

Comment: That only works with Tab hosts. Not the way it's done with getActionBar().addTab(... style

Answer (score 3):

I created the following method to select any tab with the text on view.

```
public MainScreen clickOnTab(String tabText) {
    onView(allOf(withClassName(endsWith("TabView")),
            withChild(withText(tabText)),
            withParent(withParent(withId(R.id.main_activity_tab_layout)))
    )).perform(scrollTo()).perform(click());
    return this;
}
```

and in order to call this method simply call the method like below:

```
MainScreen.getInstance().clickOnTab("Tab Name");
```

Cheers