# Perform click on tabText or perform swipe on viewPager returns NoMatchingViewException using Espresso Framework

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-espresso, android-tablayout, android-instrumentation

My goal is to be able to navigate to my tabs; may it be through swipe or click action;

Inside my RelativeLayout is below:

```
<RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/appbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
         android:id="@+id/tab"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ...>
         <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem1"
            android:text="Tab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
         <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:text="Tab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
   </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
   <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager 
      android:id="@+id/viewPager"
      android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried this [Selecting Native Tabs while Espresso testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124632/selecting-native-tabs-while-espresso-testing/25173439), and a lot more suggestions, like specifying the tabText or the tabItem IDs `onView(withText("Tab2")).perform(click());`; modifying my xml layout as shown in this answer [Android ViewPager displaying views on top of TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366706/android-viewpager-displaying-views-on-top-of-tablayout) but these still result to `NoMatchingViewException`.

**I've tried setting the height of viewPager from `wrap_content` to `0dp`, and it can now see my tabText. But I don't want that since my viewPager now is not visible on screen.**

Have seen one question that might be related to my problem yet there's no answers yet. Please also check it out [Perform click to tabtext under TabLayout always gives NoMatchingViewException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286153/perform-click-to-tabtext-under-tablayout-always-gives-nomatchingviewexception)

---

In case this might help;
This tabbedActivity is shown after `btn.perform(click())`. The one triggering the event is from my MainActivity - declared in my ActivityRule `ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class);`

Is my problem in the layout? 
How can I successfully switch to my two tabs?

---

Is there any chance that Espresso won't be able to read SecondActivity?
I try to debug it line by line; after clicking button that leads to next activity, the next line of code is not read (which in this case is the text/IDs from secondActivity). When I try to hit back from emulator(goes back to MainActivity), I am now able to step into the next line of code (in this case results to NoMatchingViewException) since that text/ID that I'm validating does not belong to the MainActivity, it should be from the SecondActivity.

Comment: Could you please add full xml code?

Comment: @BirjuVachhani, updated the xml to have the full layout. Please see

Comment: Where is the height and width attributes of all the views?

Comment: Now updated. Sorry, late edit.

Comment: Could you post your failure log? You may be having asynchronous issue, like background thread between your activities or transitions.

Comment: @Aaron, I only get `androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "Tab2"
If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:android.widget.ListView{d637f4e xxxxxxx etc}`

Comment: @Aaron, I added the last paragraph. Maybe you have an experience

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add this class to your test directory:

**TabsMatcher.java**

```java
public class TabsMatcher implements ViewAction {

    int position;

    TabsMatcher(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
        return isDisplayed();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Click on tab";
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
        if (view instanceof TabLayout) {
            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view;
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
            if (tab != null) {
                tab.select();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this in your tests:

```java
@Test
public void myTest(){
    onView(withId(R.id.tab)).perform(new TabsMatcher(position))
}
```

Comment: Resulted to `androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: com.example.test:id/tab`. Most probably my viewPager covers up everything? But I've set it to be below of the TabLayout.